# Three20 crash when using PhotoSource

Tags: iphone, three20

In my app I send a request to get images from flickr. I have went 
through my app step-by-step with a breakpoint and found the app 
crashes at this line in TTURLRequest.m:

```
} else { 

    return [self.urlPath md5Hash]; 
  }
```

I get this error in the debugger:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[NSCFString md5Hash]:  unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x74409e0'

Does anybody know what is causing this? 
Thanks

Comment: What is data type of md5Hash, what is the method signature of self.urlPath ?

Comment: These are in the TTURLRequest.m file. urlPath is an NSString. Does that help?

Comment: Are you using example code from TTCatalog or did you create the photosource yourself?  If not, check out TTCatalog since he uses flickr images there.  I'm guessing you just don't have everything included in the project properly, but that's just a guess.

Comment: I am using that same code in my project but I get the crash.

Answer (score 1):

check your "other linker flag" settings. This could happen if you have not set your "other linker flags" properly. It has to be -ObjC and -all_load. any mistake in uppercase or lowercase will also cause this problem